# Why cant I remove a node from my circular linked list by allocating it to the next node?

Tags: java, linked-list

This program accepts user data (names) and outputs the information on the screen. Then asks the user which to name to remove from the linked list.

I'm having difficulty with my program involving deleting. I cant seem to remove the nodes because of an error I'm reviving with "next" and "prev" (See below).

```
public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));        

        Node node, head, tail; // node is where string data is kept

        String name, delete;
        int count = 0;

        head = null; // initialize the head  and tail to null
        tail = null;


        System.out.print ("Enter a name. Type q to end inputting.");

        name = stdin.readLine ();

        node = new Node (name);
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
        tail = node;

        contestant = null;

        do // loop to create new nodes for the linked list using user data
        {

            System.out.print ("Enter a name. Type q to end.");
            name = stdin.readLine ();

            // create a new node if the user has not decided to quit
            if (!contestant.equals ("q"))
            {
                node = new Node (name);
                node.next = head;
                count++;
                head = node;  // update the head to point to the new front of the list

            }
        }
        while (!contestant.equals ("q"));  // loop continues until "q" selected      

        System.out.println ();


        do // display contestants
        {
            System.out.println (node.data);
            node = node.next;
        }
        while (node != null);  // loop until the end of lists is reached

        //////////////////////////////////////////Delete///////////////////////////////////////////


        boolean Delete; // check to see if deleted

        Node listNode; // node to delete

        System.out.println ("Enter a node to be removed:");
        delete = stdin.readLine ();

        listNode = new Node (delete);

        Node temp = listNode;

        do
        {
            if (temp.listNode () == node) 
            {
                node.prev = temp.previous (); 
                node.next = temp.next (); 

                if (prev != listNode.next) 
                {
                    prev.next () = next; 
                    next.previous () = prev; // removed 
                    return true; 
                }

                else
                {
                    return false; // only one node 
                }
                temp = temp.next (); 
            }
        }
        while (temp != listNode);   // couldnt remove
        return false; 
}
}
```

The Node class:

```
public class Node
{
    Node next, prev;
    String data;

    public Node (String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my implementation, maybe that'll help you figure it out: https://github.com/Vannevelj/Exercises/tree/master/Exercises/src/com/datastructures/doublylinkedlist. Any specific reason why you don't use functions? Also: you're not saving any references to the next and previous node in your Node class, that's something you should add as well. And show us the error!

Comment: The problem is that I cant run the program because of multiple syntax errors within the delete portion. The values dont exist